# Python returns local variable referenced before error

Tags: python

- I edit this post for your comments. Thank you :-)
- The prev_fs_cell is the variable whose value can be nan or str. (ex. nan <-> "1,244,234" )
  If prev_fs_cell is nan, I want not to process self._strat(self, curr_year), but it has an error...

```
## GLOBAL & API ###
STOCK_START="2015.01.01"
FS_START="2014.01.01"
END="2021.09.01"
SHORT=10
LONG=60
CURR_YEAR=2021

API_key=dart_config.API_key
DART=OpenDartReader(API_key)

account_nm_list=["유동자산","비유동자산","유동부채","비유동부채","자산총계","부채총계","매출액","영업이익","당기순이익"]
KOSPI_stock_code=stock.get_market_ticker_list(market="KOSPI")

class Strategy():
  def __init__(self):
    self.buy_signal=pd.DataFrame(columns=['open','unit'])
    self.sell_signal = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open', 'unit'])
    self.trade = pd.DataFrame(columns=['stock', 'cash'])
    self.position=0
    self.unit=1
    self.cash=100000000 # 1억
    
  def set_data(self, indicator_data, finance_data):
    self.indicator_data=indicator_data
    self.indicator_data.rename(columns={self.indicator_data.columns[0]:'date'}, inplace=True)
    self.indicator_data = self.indicator_data.set_index('date')
    self.indicator_data.index = pd.to_datetime(self.indicator_data.index, format="%Y-%m-%d")
    self.fs_data=finance_data
    self.fs_data.rename(columns={self.fs_data.columns[0]:'year'}, inplace=True)
    self.fs_data = self.fs_data.set_index('year')

    self.min_year=int(self.fs_data.index.min()) # str type
    
  def _buy(self, row):
    if (row['open']*self.unit) <= self.cash:
      new_buy_row = pd.Series([row['open'], self.unit], index = self.buy_signal.columns, name=str(row.name))
      self.buy_signal = self.buy_signal.append(new_buy_row)
      self.position += self.unit
      
      stock_amt = self.position * row['open']
      self.cash -= row['open']*self.unit
      new_trade_row = pd.Series([stock_amt, self.cash], index = self.trade.columns, name = str(row.name))
      self.trade = self.trade.append(new_trade_row)
    
  def _sell(self, row):
    new_sell_row = pd.Series([row['open'], int(self.position/4)+1], index = self.sell_signal.columns, name=str(row.name))
    self.sell_signal = self.sell_signal.append(new_sell_row)
    self.position -= int(self.position/4)+1

    stock_amt = self.position * row['open']
    self.cash += row['open']*self.unit
    new_trade_row = pd.Series([stock_amt, self.cash], index = self.trade.columns, name = str(row.name))
    self.trade = self.trade.append(new_trade_row)
    
  def _strat(self, row, curr_year):
    fs = self.fs_data
    prev_year = curr_year - 1

    curr_rev = int(fs.loc[curr_year, '매출액'].replace(",",""))
    prev_rev = int(fs.loc[prev_year, '매출액'].replace(",",""))
    rev_growth=(curr_rev-prev_rev)/prev_rev

    curr_ni = int(fs.loc[curr_year, '당기순이익'].replace(",",""))
    prev_ni = int(fs.loc[prev_year, '당기순이익'].replace(",",""))
    ni_growth=(curr_ni-prev_ni)/prev_ni

    curr_asset = int(fs.loc[curr_year, '유동자산'].replace(",",""))
    noncurr_asset = int(fs.loc[prev_year, "비유동자산"].replace(",",""))
    curr_asset_rat = curr_asset / noncurr_asset

    if (row.rsi<0.65) & (rev_growth>0.005) & (1.3< curr_asset_rat):# & (curr_asset_rat<2.3):
      self._buy(row)
        
    elif (row.Golden == False):
      if ni_growth <= 0.001 :
        if self.position:
          self._sell(row)
          # a=1
                  
  def run(self):
    dates = self.indicator_data.index
    fs = self.fs_data
    #print(fs.index)

    for date in dates:
      curr_year = date.year
      row = self.indicator_data.loc[date]
      #print(curr_year, type(curr_year))
      #pdb.set_trace()
      try:
        curr_fs_cell = fs.loc[curr_year].iloc[0].replace(",","")
        try:
          prev_fs_cell = fs.loc[curr_year-1].iloc[0].replace(",","")
        except:
          prev_fs_cell = None
      except:
        curr_fs_cell = None
      
      if (curr_fs_cell == None) | (prev_fs_cell == None):
        #print("fs data is empty")
        continue
      else:
        #print(prev_fs_cell)
        self._strat(row, curr_year)
      

      
for code in KOSPI_stock_code:
  FS = load_data("FS_"+code)
  indi = load_data("indicator_"+code)

  today = dt.today()

  strategy = Strategy()
  strategy.set_data(indi, FS)
  strategy.run()

  buy = strategy.buy_signal
  sell = strategy.sell_signal
  unit = strategy.unit

  remain_stock = buy['unit'].sum() - sell['unit'].sum()
  remain = int(get_data(str(code)+".KS", today).iloc[0]['open'])*int(remain_stock)

  total_buy = int((buy['open'].sum()))*unit
  total_sell = int(sell['open'].sum())*unit
  
  profit = int(remain) + int(total_sell) - int(total_buy)

  if total_buy:
    return_rate = profit / total_buy 
    trade = strategy.trade
    total_return_per_day = trade['stock']+trade['cash']
    residual = total_return_per_day - return_rate
    sample_var = residual**2 / (trade.shape[0]-1)
    sample_dev = np.sqrt(sample_var)

    Rf=0.01
    sharp = (return_rate - Rf) / (sample_dev)

    results[code]['return'] = return_rate
    results[code]['sharp'] = sharp

  else:
    print("No buy due to strict condition")
```

I have tried to make backtest code for investing into Korean stocks by using financial sheet and stock price sheet and indicator sheet.
And my code return error like the below.

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-caf2b218f860> in <module>()
     10   strategy = Strategy()
     11   strategy.set_data(indi, FS)
---> 12   strategy.run()
     13 
     14   buy = strategy.buy_signal

<ipython-input-12-2d41db386a22> in run(self)
     84         curr_fs_cell = None
     85 
---> 86       if (curr_fs_cell == None) | (prev_fs_cell == None):
     87         #print("fs data is empty")
     88         continue

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev_fs_cell' referenced before assignment
```

Actually there is no global variable whose name is prev_fs_cell, but it is only in that class. Why this error occurs?

Comment: Your code is almost certainly incomplete; you only write to `prev_fs_cell`, you never read from it, so `UnboundLocalError` *can't* occur. I'm guessing you removed code you consider unimportant from the example, and didn't verify it remained a [MCVE]. Odds are the problem is you use that variable later, and either `dates` is empty, or exceptions are occurring on the `curr_fs_cell = fs.loc[curr_year].iloc[0].replace(",","")` line, and you're silently catching and ignoring them all. [Bare excepts are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30294977/364696), and silently ignoring them is worse.

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we can see the failing line.

Comment: Yeah, the more complete code confirms that line is part of the problem; the error occurs because the line raises an exception, and you catch it, skipping the code that gives `prev_fs_cell` a value. It would be okay if you had correctly used short-circuiting boolean operators in the subsequent test, but you didn't, so both sides of the bitwise-or got evaluated and it broke. So just fixing the test to the canonical `if (curr_fs_cell is None) or (prev_fs_cell is None):` would be enough to fix the problem (whether it's logically correct is up to you).